# Is there any other way to check the users will be online/offline instead of setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I want to check the users will be online/offline. Initially, I planned to implement this by using jQuery setTimeout or setInterval functions. But, it will be causing performance problems in servers. So, I am expecting some other solutions instead of these functions.

Comment: Use websockets. You can then count the number of connections a user has to your site. If it's `0`, they're offline. However, your question is far too broad. This is quite a straightforward subject to research. Here's what I found on a first hit for Google. It's for a rails app, but the pattern is the same regardless of server infrastructure: https://www.ryanepp.com/blog/how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-online

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your quick response, I am a newbie for WebSockets concepts. However, let me try.